# Toggle navigation bar not toggling properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, navigationbar

I have just created a responsive toggle navigation bar. Everything is working fine, just one problem is that it is not toggling properly as it should. 
Dropdown menu can be seen when it on mouse click, and as soon as I release the mouse click, the dropdown menu disappears (refer http://testpage187.tumblr.com/). It's happening for both Desktop and Mobile (as it is responsive, I think it will work as same for both). I think the problem is with the javascript code. Please look into it. I am attaching my codes here. Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: #262626;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header .logo {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

header nav ul li.sub-menu:before {
  content: '\f0d7';
  font-family: 'fontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  right: 5px;
}

header nav ul li.active.sub-menu:before {
  content: '\f0d8';
}

header nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li:active ul {
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

header nav ul li ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a:active {
  background: #2196f3;
}

.menu-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  header {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  header nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    background: #333;
    top: 50px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  header nav.active {
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
  }
  header nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
  header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
  }
  header nav ul li.active ul {
    position: relative;
    background: #003e6f;
  }
  header nav ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="sub-menu">New  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">New 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" class="sub-menu">Contact  <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Contact 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Comment: One part of the toggle is working, but when I click on "NEW" & "CONTACT", it's sub-menu opens only on the mouse click and disappear when I leave the mouse button. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

You had a problem in the CSS. You were adding a "state" `:active` instead of a class `.active` on the siblings.

CSS problem:

```
header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a:active {
  background:#2196f3;
}

header nav ul li:active ul{
    display:block;
}
```

CSS Solution:

```
header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a.active {
  background:#2196f3;
}

header nav ul li.active ul{
    display:block;
}
```

And also I fixed a `top` displacement.

Here's the fiddle: [Toggle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/81tcnp69/)

Comment: One more problem. When I click on "NEW" it covers the two menu buttons below it "Contact & About". How can I make them move downwards when relatively with resepect to opening & closing of sub-menu?

Comment: Here the problem would be the 'height: calc(100vh - 50px);', actually it depends on what behavior do you want with it. A first solution is to set the height to 'min-height: 100vh;'     PD: Remember to vote the answer :)

Comment: I am still under 15 reputation, so it says my vote won't be counted. Once I am over 15 reputations, a sure upvote for you. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I need a little more help. (1) When I click on the menu it's sub-menu appears, but the background color of my active menu disappears, I want it to appear the same color when hovered. (2) Also, I want the sub-menu hide when clicked outside of the menu and sub-menu box. How to do that?

Comment: Well just as we selected an event when clicking the sub-menu, we create an event when 'not' clicking the same, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dj0p41hm/

Answer (score 0):

One simple css class as solution

add below to your style.

```
header nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

then remove all scripts